# Optimize Temporary Table on Presto/Hive SQL

Tags: sql, hive, amazon-redshift, presto

I would like to optimize my computation time for queries ran on PRESTO/HIVE SQL. One of the techniques I used to do on Redshift was to improve efficiency of temporary tables as in the following :

```
BEGIN;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE my_temp_table(
column_a varchar(128) encode lzo,
column_b char(4) encode bytedict)
distkey (column_a) -- Assuming you intend to join this table on column_a
sortkey (column_b) -- Assuming you are sorting or grouping by column_b
;
INSERT INTO my_temp_table SELECT column_a, column_b FROM my_table;
COMMIT;
```

I have tried that on Presto/Hive SQL but it is not supported. Do you please know the equivalent of this technique on Presto/Hive SQL?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Redshift is relational database, Presto is a distributed SQL Query Engine. Presto currently doesn't support the creation of temporary tables and also not the creation of indexes. But you may create tables based on a SQL statement via `CREATE TABLE AS` - [Presto Documentation](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/sql/create-table-as.html)

You optimize the performance of Presto in two ways:

- Optimizing the query itself
- Optimizing how the underlying data is stored

One of the best articles around is [Top 10 Performance Tuning Tips for Amazon Athena](https://aws.amazon.com/de/blogs/big-data/top-10-performance-tuning-tips-for-amazon-athena/) - Athena is a AWS Service based on Presto 0.172 and therefore the tips should also work for Presto.

Answer (score 2):

I am not a Redshift expert but it seems you want to precompute a data set, distributing it and sorting by selected columns, so that it is faster to query.

This corresponds to Presto Hive connector ability to:

- partition data -- data with same value in partitioning column(s) will form a single partition, which is a folder on storage; do not use partitioning on high cardinality columns. This is defined using `partitioned_by` table property
- bucket data -- data is grouped in files using hash of bucketing column(s); this is similar to partitioning to a certain extent. This is defined using `bucketed_by` and `bucket_count` table properties.
- sort data -- within data file, data is sorted by given column(s). This is defined using `sorted_by` table property.

See examples in [Trino (formerly Presto SQL) Hive connector documentation](https://trino.io/docs/current/connector/hive.html#examples)

Note: while i realize documentation is scarce at the moment, i filed [an issue to improve](https://github.com/prestosql/presto/issues/5581) it. In the meantime, you can get additional information on [Trino (formerly Presto SQL) community slack](https://trino.io/slack.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot Piotr for your help! 

I am actually trying to optimize queries that use with statement. For example,
WITH sub1 as (
SELECT 1 AS x
),
sub2 as (
SELECT x AS y
)
SELECT * FROM sub2

And I want instead of default storing temporary tables sub1 and sub2 to optimize their storage.

From my understanding is that "partitioned_by, bucketed_by and sorted_by" can be used to optimize storage of database tables not subqueries. Is that correct?

Comment: In Presto `WITH` (the common table expression) is inlined (you can think of this as a `VIEW`). This is reasonable if you use `WITH` just to structure your query in a more readable way. If the common table expression is referenced multiple times, you may need to capture it with an explicit `CREATE TABLE`.